# Remove zoom in zoom out effect using css

Tags: html, css

I want remove zoom in zoom out effect from mobile view but not getting solution,

```
.whats_next_float .lets_go_wrapper img.logo_img {
    animation: zoominout 3s infinite;
}

animation: zoominout 3s infinite;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-fill-mode: none;
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-name: zoominout;
}
```

Anyone have idea then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the CSS `animation` property to none.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .whats_next_float .lets_go_wrapper img.logo_img {
    -webkit-animation: none;
    -moz-animation: none;
    -o-animation: none;
    -ms-animation: none;
    animation: none;
  }
}
```